# JQGrid is not working in ASP.net mvc 4?

Tags: model-view-controller, jqgrid

```
This is controller code:
using JQGird.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace JQGird.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /Home/

        public ActionResult Index()
        {

            return View();

        }


        public JsonResult EmployeeDetail()
        {

            Database1Entities db = new Database1Entities();
            var employeedata = db.Empployees.Select(data => new
            {
                data.Id,
                data.Name,
                data.Designation,
                data.Address,
                data.Salary
            });
            var jsondat = new
            {
                total = 1,
                page = 1,
                records = db.Empployees.ToList().Count,
                rows = employeedata


            };

            return Json(jsondat, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }

    }
}
```

and this is view of index action method

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}
<header>
<script>

    $(document).ready(function () {


        $('#grid').jqGrid({

            url: '/Home/EmployeeDetails',
            datatype: 'json',
            myType: 'GET',
            colNames: ['Id', 'Name', 'Designation', 'Address', 'Salary'],
            colModel: [
                { name: 'Id', index: 'Id' },
                { name: 'Name', index: 'Name' },
                { name: 'Designation', index: 'Designation' },
                { name: 'Address', index: 'Address' },
                { name: 'Salary', index: 'Salary' }
            ],
            jsonReader: {
                root: 'rows',
                page: 'page',
                total: 'total',
                reocords: 'records',
                id: '0',
                repeatitems: false
            },
            pager: $('#pager'),
            rowNum: 5,
            rowList: [2, 5, 10],
            width: 600,
            viewrecords: true,
            caption: 'Jqgrid MVC Tutorial'
        });

    });

</script>

<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.jqGrid.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.jqGrid.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/i18n/grid.locale-en.js"></script>
<link href="~/Content/jquery.jqGrid/ui.jqgrid.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/Content/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</header>

<h1>Records of employees</h1>
<div>
    <table id="grid">
    </table>
<div id="pager"></div>


</div>
```

When i run the application, i t only show  data. I have also check that the Json data is coming successffully to the view but jqgrid is not working. What mistakes i am doing?

---

```
HTML of the page
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Index</title>
    <link href="/Content/site.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

    <script src="/Scripts/modernizr-2.5.3.js"></script>

</head>
<body>



<h1>Records of employees</h1>
<div>
    <table id="grid">
    </table>
<div id="pager"></div>


</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {


        $('#grid').jqGrid({

            url: '/Home/EmployeeDetail',
            datatype: 'json',
            //myType: 'GET',
            loadonce: true,
            colNames: ['Id', 'Name', 'Designation', 'Address', 'Salary'],
            colModel: [
                { name: 'Id', index: 'Id' },
                { name: 'Name', index: 'Name' },
                { name: 'Designation', index: 'Designation' },
                { name: 'Address', index: 'Address' },
                { name: 'Salary', index: 'Salary' }
            ],
            jsonReader: {
                root: 'rows',
                page: 'page',
                total: 'total',
                reocords: 'records',
                id: '0',
                repeatitems: false
            },
            pager: $('#pager'),
            rowNum: 5,
            rowList: [2, 5, 10],
            width: 600,
            viewrecords: true,
            caption: 'Jqgrid MVC Tutorial'
        });

    });

</script>
<link href="/Content/jquery.jqGrid/ui.jqgrid.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="/Content/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>

<script src="/Scripts/i18n/grid.locale-en.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.jqGrid.min.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.jqGrid.js"></script>















</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HTML page have wrong order of JavaScripts which you includes.

- It's important to understand that jqGrid is jQuery plugin. So one have to include first jQuery and only then one can includes jqGrid JavaScript files.
- In the same way you use `$(document).ready(function () {...});` which contains `$` and `.ready` defined by jQuery, but you use the code **before** you included jQuery file `jquery-1.9.1.min.js`.
- The next error: you included both non-minimized jqGrid `jquery.jqGrid.js` and then minimized version of the same file `jquery.jqGrid.min.js`. It's wrong. You should include only one from the files.
- One more problem could exist in the order of the main jqGrid file (`jquery.jqGrid.min.js`, `jquery.jqGrid.js` or `jquery.jqGrid.src.js`) and the corresponding locale file `grid.locale-en.js`. There are different requirements for different versions of jqGrid and different forks, but the recommended order which works in all versions of jqGrid is: first include locale file (like `grid.locale-en.js`) and then the main jqGrid file (like `jquery.jqGrid.min.js`).
- you skipped `<body>...</body>` after `</header>`.
- The code of `EmployeeDetail` action don't uses any parameters which jqGrid send. You don't implemented any paging and sorting in the server code. Instead of that you just return *all data at once*. You should use `loadonce: true` options in the case. jqGrid will load all the data and then it will use sorting, paging and filtering *on the client side*. I hope that you use jqGrid in version higher as 3.7 which implemented support of `loadonce: true`. If you use `loadonce: true` option then the `total`, `page` and `records` properties of the server response will be ignored. Thus you can reduce the code of the server side and use `return Json(employeedata, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);` instead of `return Json(jsondat, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);`.
- There are no `myType` option, but there are exist `mtype` option which default value is `'GET'`. So you should remove `myType: 'GET'` option which will be ignored by jqGrid.
- Some options of jqGrid can depend from the version of jqGrid which you use. I would recommend you to use `gridview: true, autoencode: true, height: "auto"`. I would recommend you to remove unneeded `index` properties from all columns defined in `colModel`. Instead of that you can add `key: true` option for `Id` column. It will inform jqGrid to use the values from the columns as the values of `id` attribute of the rows (`id` of `<td>` elements). The `jsonReader` can be removed or you can use `jsonReader: { repeatitems: false }` or `jsonReader: { repeatitems: false, root: function (obj) { return obj; } }`. If you use recent version of jqGrid then no `jsonReader` will be required.
- I mentioned above multiple times about versions which you use. I would recommend you to update jQuery 1.9.1 which you use currently to jQuery 1.11.3 or 2.1.4. Moreover I would recommend you to use the latest version of free jqGrid which you can get either from NuGet (see [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/free-jqGrid/)), used URLs from CDN (see [the wiki article](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/Access-free-jqGrid-from-different-CDNs)) or to download the latest sources from [GitHub](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) directly.

Comment: First of all thanks for detailed answer. I am not using <body> tag because it used with layout file. Now i change the order of jquey file as you said but ir still not working.

Comment: @Hiba: You don't included `_Layout.cshtml` file and not exact View code. Tyxpically one don't include `<head>` in the way in the View. I recommend you to open the source of HTML page in web browser to see what will be generated by MVC. Alternatively you can just use HTML page directly instead of the view.

Comment: @Hiba: You can use `@{ Layout = null; }` in the view and include **all** HTML content in the View, starting with `<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en"><head>...` and till `</body></html>`. One can use `_Layout.cshtml` of cause, but you should first have *working* code and then you can use shared `_Layout.cshtml` in more elegant way.

Comment: Solved. The mistake was the conflict between script references also include in layout file.now it works like a champ. Thanks oleg you are very helpful